# apt-get reports "no installation candidate" randomly for no good reason

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2

When I provision Ubuntu 14.04 boxes in Amazon AWS, I begin with an official Canonical AMI (specifically `ami-f0c52390`), boot the instance, and run a provisioning script. One of the first things the script does is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-dev python-virtualenv ruby
```

Most of the time this works great. Sometimes though, maybe 1 in 10 times, the `apt-get install` will fail with the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install python-dev python-virtualenv ruby
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package python-virtualenv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package ruby is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
python

E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ruby' has no installation candidate
```

If I terminate the instance and start a new one -- same AMI, same apt sources, same script, *same everything*, it will usually work the next time I try it.

Usually I can tell the install will fail by watching the output of `apt-get update`. The mirrors being used are distinctly different between successful and failing runs.

**GOOD:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:3 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [262 kB]
Get:4 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,352 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [106 kB]
Get:7 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [151 kB]
Get:8 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,946 B]
Get:9 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [713 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:11 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:12 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [339 kB]
Get:13 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:14 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [361 kB]
Get:15 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,227 B]
Get:16 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3,699 B]
Get:17 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease
Get:18 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [182 kB]
Get:19 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Get:20 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [8,661 B]
Get:21 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [28 B]
Get:22 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Get:23 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [34.0 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1,350 kB]
Get:25 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,898 B]
Get:26 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [9,787 B]
Get:27 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]
Get:28 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [40.9 kB]
Get:29 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,571 B]
Get:30 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en [5,843 B]
Get:31 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1,215 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Get:32 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en [28 B]
Get:33 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [35.5 kB]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:34 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources [1,064 kB]
Get:35 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources [5,433 B]
Get:36 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources [6,399 kB]
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [34.0 kB]
Get:38 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources [174 kB]
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5,859 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages [132 kB]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en [102 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en [3,457 B]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 22.5 MB in 1min 36s (234 kB/s)
```

**BAD:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease
Get:4 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [713 kB]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty/main Translation-en
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [431 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [339 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.2 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [361 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7227 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3699 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [182 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58.5 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages [132 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [125 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [5859 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4991 B]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [236 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2570 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3206 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [1350 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [73.8 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en [762 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en [102 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en [3457 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4089 kB]
Fetched 15.0 MB in 8s (1814 kB/s)
```

What's going on here? Am I sometimes hitting a bad mirror? Could the instance's networking not be fully up or something? Why is the behavior non-deterministic, and always fixable simply by trying the script again on a new instance?